# Softlayer deletion of manual snapshot

Tags: rest, api, curl, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Good Morning,

1. Snapshot creation successful via cURL REST commands   These take
   anywhere between 1-5 minutes before they are visable via GUI or
   getSnapshotsForVolume.
2. I do not see a reference to delete any snapshot (manual or automated) via the service, deletion of scheduled snapshots appears to be utilization based upon value defined for the schedule.

I know this function should exist, as option is available via the GUI.

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yep it exists is the deleteObject method

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_network_storage_iscsi/deleteobject

when you create a new manual snapshot it returns an softlayer_network_storage_iscsi object see:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_network_storage_iscsi/createsnapshot

you just need to make to sure to use the ID of that snapshot in the deleteObject method

Comment: Thanks, I need to change my thought process on how some of these terms are utilized.  Accepted solution.